# Numerical decomposition of polynomials into second-order terms

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

I am trying to numerically decompose real univariate polynomials into a product of second order polynomials. I have attempted to do this using [Bairstow's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairstow%27s_method), and while this works fine for most even-order polynomials (odd-order polynomials obviously don't work as-is, but can easily be worked around), there are some where the method fails as the Jacobian becomes singular, e.g. $x^{16} + x^{12} + x^8 + x^4 + 1$ with the guess $x^2$. Which alternative methods work? As I actually *want* the second-order polynomials and not pairs of complex zeros (that I may first need to match up), I would strongly prefer methods specialized for real polynomials that directly extract the second-order terms. The polynomials I am looking at often have multiplicity $\ge 2$ of some of the roots. Parallel extraction of all terms would be nice to have, but not strictly necessary.

Comment: If some initial guess fails, try again with some other random quadratic polynomial. Is that not possible for some reason? For roots with multiplicity, the usual detection strategies apply (e. g., test if 3 iterates are almost on one line, or if the residuum fails to reduce by at least a factor of 2), then do mitigation like steps of double step size.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Honestly, not a big fan of nondeterministic approaches, but I should probably try it. However, I found the following in Brodlie 1975: "Henrici [6,  p.  114] and Carrano [5] have between them proved the  following result: if $\alpha_1$,  $\alpha_2$  are the  roots of $(z^2  + p^*z  +  q^*)$,  then  $J^* \neq 0$ if and  only if $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ are simple, distinct roots of $P(z)$, or real, equal roots of multiplicity two. Thus, in particular, if $(z^2  + p^*z  +  q^*)$ is a quadratic factor of multiplicity greater than one, then  $J^* = 0$. "

Comment: https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1975-29-131/S0025-5718-1975-0381283-7/S0025-5718-1975-0381283-7.pdf

Comment: Yes, if the Jacobian were regular, the roots would be simple. But that is only a concern directly at the root location. For the iteration this means only that the floating point precision gets increasingly more imprecise due to increasing catastrophic cancellation in the derivative terms.